# static HTML to joomla

Tags: html, joomla

Hey I have a problem with converting my HTML to joomla so it can be added in the joomla admin pannel.

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#maps" class="smoothScroll">Map</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://thatdarkrpserver.com/forum/">Comunity</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tutorials" class="smoothScroll">Tutorials</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#admin/staff" class="smoothScroll">Admins/Staff</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

So that is my HTML code for my menu but I want to be able to add/edit menu items in the admin pannel of joomla.

But what code do I add than I cant find a clear tutorial on internet about this.
I hope somebody can help me.

**NOTE:** I have my template already in joomla I only want to be able to add/edit menu items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the menu items through the joomla /administrator. Go to Menus -> Main menu -> Add New Menu Item. For both external urls and anchor urls, choose System links -> External url. Write the name of the menu item, and add the link.

The markup will be similar but slightly different than your static example. You can modify the markup by overriding the menu output ([tutorial](https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides)), or you can change your css/scripts to make it work with the joomla output, whichever you prefer.